# Maximize the number of simultaneous http-downloads

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'am trying to perform as many as possible simultaneous http-downloads an IPad2 ( ios6.0 ). This is pure for testing what is possible on this device. Even not interested in GUI performance ( not important if it doesn't respond )

I've created a special HTTP-server that sends for x minutes data to the client. The data received is of no importance. I just measure the speed an how many concurrent downloads. 
I've implemented 2 different ways of scheduling 12 HTTP-requests.

### NSOperation

One is done by using NSOperation objects in a Queue and set the NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount on 12

### NSThread

The second implementation is by creating 12 NSThreads that perform a synchro http-request.

The requests are all sent to the same destination IP.

### Observation

What I observe is that in both cases the 6th to 12th request get a TimeOut ( errorcode -1001 ). If 1 put the timeout-value to 80.0 seconds, I see that the 6th download starts when the 1st is done.

### Questions

- Is there in IOS a limit on how many concurrent downloads?
- Is there an other way to perform these concurrent downloads ?
- Is there a way to bind a thread to a core ( so that it doesn't get an interrupt, like cpuaffinity in C++ ) or thread priority

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can have maximum of 5 simultaneous connections to the same server. It's an iOS fixed limit and it's probably because of some http protocol constraints. You can read a bit more info [here](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/01/on-ios-url-connection-parallelism-and.html).

Comment: This is indeed what I observe at the moment. So I'm not the only one to notice this. So I can assume my implementation wasn't wrong...

Comment: Yes, although the scenario with the 12 `NSThreads` is a bit more expensive than the first one...

Comment: is there an apple link which specifies that  ?

Comment: This has been reduced to 4 concurrent connections as of iOS 7. There is no Apple link that I know off, but [here is some code you can use to test the limit](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/01/on-ios-url-connection-parallelism-and.html?m=1).

Comment: If it is indeed a per server limit, you could theoretically circumvent this limit by using a wildcard subdomain DNS configuration and generating random subdomains for each request. Obviously this is only possible if you have the ability to set this up on the server side.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is still correct. The maximum of 4 simultaneous connections that are allowed are per NSURL session: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost. The app is allowed to make more requests at the same time using different sessions.

Answer (score 4):

Just a bump to this in case anyone is still looking. I see it to be 4 simultaneous on my iPhone6S+. Here were my test steps:

- I wrote a PHP script that does sleep(10) before echoing something back.
- I added a button (so I can execute well after startup)
- Hitting that button triggers 30 simultaneous NSURLConnections (synchronous requests, but each in a separate thread), and an NSLog.
- The completion for each does an NSLog

The results are like clockwork. The first responses (4 of them) come back 12 seconds after the request (presumably 2 seconds to turn the radio on or whatever), but then each subsequent block of 4 responses come 10 seconds after the prior block of 4. All 4 at a time.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

After looking into this for a project I found something in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost) for NSURLSessionConfiguration.

From Apple's documentation --

> This property determines the maximum number of simultaneous
>   connections made to each host by tasks within sessions based on this
>   configuration.
>
> This limit is per session, so if you use multiple sessions, your app
>   as a whole may exceed this limit. Additionally, depending on your
>   connection to the Internet, a session may use a lower limit than the
>   one you specify.
>
> The default value is 6 in OS X, or 4 in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there in IOS a limit on how many concurrent downloads?

This is, by the way, a per server-based limit, not an iOS limit. If you try doing this from different servers at the same time, you will see that you can exceed your current limit.

> Is there an other way to perform these concurrent downloads?

Obviously you could do something with GCD, too, manually managing concurrent requests, but I think `NSOperationQueue` is an excellent solution and see no reason to look further than that. I certainly don't see any advantages to using threads, either.

You should benchmark the total elapsed time as the number of concurrent requests increases, but I'm sure you'll hit a point of diminishing returns. Just having more concurrent requests does not ensure better total performance.