# React Native Image requests over a single HTTP/2 connection

Tags: react-native, amazon-cloudfront, http2, multiplexing, react-image

We have many React Native [`<Image>`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) components rendering per screen and are witnessing performance issues [due to many simultaneous http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15089409/1337422). Opening and closing a connection is expensive, and having too many simultaneous connections can hit limitations that cause timeouts.

[HTTP/2 features multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517829/what-does-multiplexing-mean-in-http-2), allowing multiple requests and response messages between the client and server to be in flight at the same time over a single connection, instead of multiple connections, which improves page load times.

[CloudFront supports HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, and HTTP/1 by default depending on the version the client sends up in the request header.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-http2/)

We noticed that our React Native app is sending HTTP/1.1 as the version in the request headers for any GET on an `<Image>`. Unlike popular apps, we're opening and closing a single connection for each GET. **How do we make sure React Native Image requests use HTTP/2 and share a connection?**

*(Our images all share the same CloudFront domain.)*

[image]

---

**Edit - More Information:**

Our CloudFront distribution supports HTTP/2:

[image]

And it appears the client and server are agreeing on h2:

[image]

Comment: Seems like `source` prop excepts [`headers`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/726d0012106316a40e36286f5eba0e881ef3bbba/Libraries/Image/ImageSource.js#L42) prop. Have you tried using that?

Comment: CloudFront supports HTTP/2 but it is not something that depends on a "request header" -- the two HTTP versions are not wire-compatible.  You're showing `ALPN` `h2` which suggests you are *trying* to use it... so, first question: have you actually enabled the HTTP/2 feature on your CloudFront distribution?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot HTTP/2 is listed as a supported version on our cloudfront distribution, yes. I've added edits to the question details.

Comment: @sgarza62 did you find a solution? We are experiencing the exact same issue

Comment: @AlbertoDallaporta no :/ ended up queuing up the images to load in the right order